# What is relationship between querySelector and API Level 1?

Tags: html, google-chrome, w3c

I checked the MDN website, querySelector is supported by Chrome 1 (2008) as well (?!); I googled few article says querySelector is defined by API Level 1, and the draft of API level 1 is in 2012; how could querySelector come out before 2012?!

Comment: querySelector appears in [this Selectors API draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/2007/WD-selectors-api-20071019/#documentselector) of October 2007. (2006 drafts called it "match" or "matchSingle")

Comment: @Alohci why don't you reply as answer?! I should mark you~!

Comment: Because the correct answer is Quentin's, which is that in general, there's no automatic ordering between specs and implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because either:

- It was a proprietary feature that was later standardised *or*
- It was developed as part of another specification (e.g. within the WHATWG's work) that never made it to a standard and the feature was spun out into a different specification in the meantime

… or both.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/ this feature has been in development since 2006. It's defined and maintained in https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/ these days.